# Does Office 2011 for Mac Document Connection work with WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, office, mac-os-x

I have a user that cannot connect to a WSS 3.0 site using the document connection from Office 2011 for Mac. It's not clear to me that WSS 3.0 is actually supported as I see this question all over different forums but there are no good answers.

SharePoint 2010 sites are perfectly fine, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, it did work at my previous job. We had many Mac users running Office 2011 and could connect to our MOSS farm with the document connector. They had to specify a site URL and provide their username as domain\username and password and they could see a list of document libraries for the site.

Comment: We are not even being prompted for credentials. It just says "Connection error". You are certain it wasn't Office 2008 for Mac?

Comment: Pretty certain it was 2011, Mac users were ahead of the windows users on office versions, 2011 vs 2007.